# Can't extend root partition

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I realize this question has been asked several times, but it's never answered so I have to start a new thread as I'm not yet allowed to comment on other's posts.

I have booted from a `gparted.iso` and attempted to extend my root partition into the adjacent free space. It just sits there for days at the point in this screen-shot:

[image: screenshot]

Has anyone encountered and resolved this?  Are there alternatives to `gparted`?

Comment: From the screen shot it appears that your root partition is already grown from 49GB to 99GB already. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I was wondering about that too, but I suspect that Curt has selected the option to grow the partition from 49GB to 99GB and then GParted updates the picture of the HD and it's partitions to show how it's _going_ to look and then goes about the business of actually doing that, where unfortunately it seems to freeze up.

Comment: Yes gparted shows what the partition will look like once completed but it never gets there.

Comment: What does the application **Disks** say about your Hard Drive? (Disks is installed by default on Ubuntu) I had an HD misbehaving and when I looked at it with 'Disks' it told me there were many many sector errors. Gparted can probably tell you the same things but with Disks it's there in the info on the first page when you open it.

Answer (score 1):

From your screenshot it looks like GParted is stuck on the disk scan.  Either that or it is finding LOTS of errors.

Reboot if you can off of a Live CD or USB and go to a terminal session.  Make sure you don't mount the partition before continuing.

Run this command: `e2fsck -f -v -c -C 0 /dev/sda1`

Now you'll be able to see what's going on with the e2fsck scan.

If you're getting many errors that can be fixed, you can either continue saying "yes", or reboot again and add `-y` to the e2fsck command above so you don't have to keep saying yes to repair every error (It will say "yes" automatically).

If you're getting bad superblock errors, you'll have to recover it this way:

Run as root (sudo) : `dumpe2fs /dev/sda1 | grep -i superblock`

You should see an output like this:

```
  Primary superblock at 0, Group descriptors at 1-2
  Backup superblock at 32768, Group descriptors at 32769-32770
  Backup superblock at 98304, Group descriptors at 98305-98306
  Backup superblock at 163840, Group descriptors at 163841-163842
  Backup superblock at 229376, Group descriptors at 229377-229378
  Backup superblock at 294912, Group descriptors at 294913-294914
  Backup superblock at 819200, Group descriptors at 819201-819202
  Backup superblock at 884736, Group descriptors at 884737-884738
  Backup superblock at 1605632, Group descriptors at 1605633-1605634
  Backup superblock at 2654208, Group descriptors at 2654209-2654210
  Backup superblock at 4096000, Group descriptors at 4096001-4096002
```

Now choose one of the backup superblock to run this command as root:

`e2fsck -f -b 32768 /dev/sda1`

And then run

`e2fsck -f -v -y -c -C 0 /dev/sda1` to do one more full check.

If everything went cleanly, and it did some repairs, try running GParted again to try resizing the partition now.

Comment: Running e2fsck -f -v -c -C /dev/sda1 generates this error:
Invalid non-numeric argument to -C ("/dev/sda1")

Comment: This is running in a VM if that matters

Comment: I changed the command to e2fsck -f -v -c -C 0 /dev/sda1 and that ran but it displays this and stays there forever:
Checking for bad blocks (read only test): 0.00% done, 0:00 elapsed. (0/0/0 errors)

Comment: Sorry, yes I forgot the zero.  The `-C 0` basically just shows a spinning bar you know it's doing something and the `-C 0` can be omitted if you want.  Try running the same command but with `fsck` instead of `e2fsck`.

Answer (score 0):

To change partition size its a good idea to work on it while its unmounted ... so boot up from a LiveCD then use gparted to modify the partition when its in an unmounted state (IE. not booted from)

Comment: This is the same answer I see on every thread where this question is asked but I have already stated that I have booted from the ISO.  The screenshot shows the drives are not mounted.

Answer (score 0):

To get further information of why it's not working, you need to expand the 
e2fsck part, so we know at which part e2fsck is stuck.

It could be cause of faulty hardware (some harddrives simply don't respond when they can't read certain sectors, because they have no real timeout, so stuff becomes very slow), but before somebody can say that we need more input.

However yes, there are alternatives, but be aware that the part it's stuck on, is an **integrity check** to avoid data loss etc.
In case you want to ignore it, you can resize the partitions manually by using parted or fdisk and resize2fs.
Be aware that resizing always comes with the risk of **losing data**.

https://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/Resize_Ext_Partition/en

This site contains a short guide on how to resize manually (and even skips the fsck part, what you should normally do and NOT skip, if possible).

What's done is basically replacing the current partition in the partition/filesystem table with a bigger one (it looks like you already had the free space)
Then make the filesystem use all the available space it has.

Else, here is a more complicated one:

https://www.howtoforge.com/linux_resizing_ext3_partitions

**You might want to try this first:**

Looking at the output of GParted, I think the space is already correct inside the table, including correct start and end sectors, so you might try:

```
sudo resize2fs -p /dev/sda1
```

This should not be harmful.

**EDIT:**
Only needed if resizing directly doesn't work.
I myself prefer the following way, buy it can break your HD badly, when not done correctly. However I think of it as more safe, as soon as you safe the backup on a USB stick.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76101/extending-a-partition-by-resize2fs

Answer (score 0):

I was initially using the i686 version of the ISO which was giving me problems.  i downloaded the AMD64 version and it worked as expected